# Структура в android приложении через ListView

Tags: android, listview, webview, структуры

Задача такая - реализовать вывод описания различных продуктов, раскиданным по категориям. Т.е. например такая структура ListView

-ListItem
--ListItem
---WebView
--ListView
---ListView
--ListItem
...

Как лучше это реализовать? желательно динамически (плюс хранить информацию для элементов списка, данные для WebView), т.к. категорий может быть много. Имеются раскиданные по нужным папкам (=категориям) данные, может как то можно этим воспользоваться? 
Надеюсь понятно объяснила. Подбросьте пожалуйста примеры или подскажите хотя бы в какую сторону искать

Comment: Будте проще, но может и expandablelistview поможет, а в listviewitem webview , плохая идея, он все таки для этого тяжеловат.

Comment: По заданию нужно именно webview, и выводится достаточно много информации для expandablelistview

Comment: Если я правильно понял, и вам действительно нужен webview как элемент списка, то вы столкнетесь с тем что, webview , не будет растягиваться относительно контента, и будет получатся скролл-в скролле, что ну вообще никак не удобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как для ReciclerView, так и для ListView Вы будете формировать адаптер на основании некоей коллекции. Для определения действия, выполняемого при выборе того или иного элемента списка, достаточно ввести в элемент коллекции дополнительное поле, определяющее это действие. Затем, уже в адаптере, на основании значения этого поля, выполнять какие то действия. Пример для ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arAdapter = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
while(// условие для выполнения ){
    HashMap<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    item.put("viewType", viewType);
    item.put("test_text", testText);
    //... Дальнейшее заполнение полей ...
    arAdapter.add(item);
    // Условие перехода к следующей записи
}
```

В адаптере прописываем следующее (для ReciclerView):

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> records;

public TestAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> records){
    this.records = records;
    this.oai = oai;
    this.accessID = accessID;
}

// Определение типа вьюхи для ее последующего создания
@Override
public final int getItemViewType(final int position){
    HashMap<String, Object> record = records.get(position);
    return (int) record.get("viewType");
}

// Создание вьюхи
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = null;
    switch(viewType){
        case 0:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_test_view_0, parent, false);
            break;
        case 1:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_test_view_1, parent, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_test_view_2, parent, false);
            break;
        default:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_test_view_default, parent, false);
            break;
    }

    return new ViewHolder(v, viewType);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    HashMap<String, Object> record = records.get(position);
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch(viewtype){
        case 0:
            holder.test_text_0.setText(record.get("testText");
            holder.onTextView0ClickListener.setPosition(position);
            break;
        case 1:
            holder.test_text_1.setText(record.get("testText");
            holder.onTextView1ClickListener.setPosition(position);
            break;
        case 2:
            holder.test_text_2.setText(record.get("testText");
            holder.onTextView2ClickListener.setPosition(position);
            break;
        case default:
            holder.test_text_def.setText(record.get("testText");
            holder.onTextViewDefClickListener.setPosition(position);
            break;
    }

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return records.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView test_text_0, test_text_1, test_text_2, test_text_def;

    public ViewHolder(View v, int viewType){
        super(v);
        this.ctx = v.getContext();
        switch(viewType){
            case 0:
                this.test_text_0 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_text_0);
                OnTextView0ClickListener onTextView0ClickListener = new OnTextView0ClickListener();
                this.test_text_0.setOnClickListener(onTextView0ClickListener);
                break;
            case 1:
                this.test_text_1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_text_1);
                OnTextView1ClickListener onTextView1ClickListener = new OnTextView1ClickListener();
                this.test_text_1.setOnClickListener(onTextView1ClickListener);                  
                break;
            case 2:
                this.test_text_2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_text_2); 
                OnTextView2ClickListener onTextView2ClickListener = new OnTextView2ClickListener();
                this.test_text_2.setOnClickListener(onTextView2ClickListener);
                break;
            case default:
                this.test_text_def = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_text_def); 
                OnTextViewDefClickListener onTextViewDefClickListener = new OnTextViewDefClickListener();
                this.test_text_def.setOnClickListener(onTextViewDefClickListener);
                break;
        }

    }
}

private class OnTextView0ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int position;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Зафиксировано нажатие по надписи в View Type = 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void setPosition(int position){
        this.position = position;
    }
}

private class OnTextView1ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int position;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Зафиксировано нажатие по надписи в View Type = 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void setPosition(int position){
        this.position = position;
    }
}

private class OnTextView2ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int position;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Зафиксировано нажатие по надписи в View Type = 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void setPosition(int position){
        this.position = position;
    }
}

private class OnTextViewDefClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int position;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Зафиксировано нажатие по надписи в View Type = default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void setPosition(int position){
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

}

Для ListView, к сожалению у меня нет готового примерчика. Но там все несколько проще:
- сведения о нашем типе вьюхи записываем в Tag;
- в процедуре ListView.OnItemClickListener() достаем из тага значение;
- на основании этого значения назначаем требуемое действие.

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации Вам потребуется минимум 2 активности. Первая будет выводить список категорий, подкатегорий и непосредственно товаров с кратким описанием. Вторая - будет выводить полное описание товара.
Наиболее оптимальный вариант организации первой активности - использование `RecyclerView`, хотя можно и `ListView`.
Вторая активность содержит `WebView` и отображает только полное описание.

Отображение категорий осуществляется следующим образом:

- на начальном этапе строится и выводится список только основных категорий;
- при выборе категории, осуществляется подгрузка списка подкатегорий или товаров (реализуется путем определения позиции выбранной записи и последующего добавления записей в адаптер с указанием позиции);
- в зависимости от того, какого типа запись была выбрана, либо осуществляется подгрузка списка подкатегорий, либо открытие описания товара.

Comment: Спасибо! а еще вопрос - хотелось бы как то автоматизировать именно процесс определения позиции выбранной записи - т.е. не для каждого пункта прописывать определенные действия, а сохранить информацию о структуре и использовать ее. Мне сказали что под iOS это можно делать с помощью файлового менеджера (не поняла как), можно ли под Андроид что то такое подобрать?

Comment: смотрите стандартный шаблон мастер-детали.